# How to check vimeo video duration and pause video after some duration in flutter?

Tags: flutter-dependencies, video-processing, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have used [vimeoplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/vimeo_player_flutter) for playing videos in my flutter app. Now the issue is vimeoplayer package does not provide any other parameter except videoId. I want to check if a video is played 10 seconds then video should be paused and a pop up should be shown to user for upgrading the app and pop up should not be dismissed by pressing hardware back button.
It will be a huge favor if you provide any help in this regard.